# Cell-level error msgs in PageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages

I've built a PageBlockTable that allows users to enter multiple values at one time. I'm trying to add some dynamic error messaging to the table to let users know which fields/cells need their attention. Its showing me the error but along with `Id+Error message` How can I remove and just have `Error: Value is required` instead?

Screen shots:
[image]

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons >       
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>

<apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accts}" var="a">                     
          <apex:column headerValue="Name" >
            <div class="requiredInput">
                <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                <apex:inputText value="{!a.Name}" required="true" />                    
            </div>
          </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Apex:

```
public PageReference save() 
{   
       try {
           //...       
       } 
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, e.getMessage()));
            return null;
           }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: If you could change it to an inputfield life would be a lot easier

Comment: Eric, yes I wish I could but the issue is that, I'm pulling data from Standard Object (Products and custom_object) for that I end-up creating a wrapper class , so my quantity is in Custom Object and all other fields are in Standard object.

Comment: And how is that a problem? In your wrapper have a Product property and one for the custom object. Set them to the value of the sObject. Or just the product, etc. You can still use sObjects in a wrapper class. Otherwise I would look into a JS / JQuery validation library instead of the controller.

Comment: let me post another question related to data model, will update you.

Comment: Eric: here is the question I have posted, please have a look at it. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140685/creating-wrapper-class-standard-custom-object